# Django with python ayncio to perform background task

Tags: python, django, python-asyncio

I have two servers,  A primary server that provide REST API to accept data from user and maintain a product details list. This server is also responsible to share product list (a subset of product data) with secondary server as soon as product is updated/created. 
also note that secondary url depends on product details, not a fix server.

Primary server written in Django. I have used django model db signal as product update, create and delete event. 
 Now problem is that I don’t want to bock my primary server REST call until it populates detail to secondary server. I need some scheduler stuff to do that, i.e. create a task to populate data in background without blocking my current thread.

I found python asyncio module comes with a function 'run_in_executor', and its working till now, But I don’t have a knowledge of the side effect over django run in wsgi server, can anyone explain ? or any other alternate ?

I found django channel, but it need extra stuff like run worker thread separately, redis cache.

Comment: Don't run background tasks in a WSGI application like Django. Use a task queue like Celery.

Comment: my app deploy in azure as webapp and unable to run more than one process. and try to avoid redis cache

Comment: Imagine you are a driving instructor and your student says "I try to avoid using the steering wheel.". What would you answer?

Comment: Thats a nice one but i am asking for a case where i am driving a car and asking for auto drive features such that i can finish my food

Answer (score 1):

You should use Django Celery for running Tasks asynchronously or in the background.

Celery is a task queue with batteries included. It’s easy to use so that you can get started without learning the full complexities of the problem it solves.

You can get more information on celery from http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#first-steps

Comment: my app deploy in azure as webapp and unable to run more than one process. and try to avoid redis cache

Comment: You can use separated redis cache that Azure provides namely **Azure Cache**. Get more details from https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/cache/

Comment: I can but side effects on cost and deployment dependence . Any alternative idea like open a separate thread in django app ready(). And run a event loop inside this thread. But again i don't have any idea of side effects. Although this is also working.